# Error = Invalid Argument from qubuf what does it mean

Tags: android, buffer, arguments

I am wondering what

```
Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
```

means.

This happens when i press the home button on my video player.
Is this something new or have other people seen something like this before.

I cannot find anything on google
especially with the tag v412_utils

this shows up on Nexus S device

LOG CAT

```
    06-08 10:57:59.257: I/windowChanged(15072): surface Created init
06-08 10:57:59.382: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(203): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-08 10:57:59.382: V/RenderScript_jni(203): surfaceDestroyed
06-08 10:57:59.386: E/Surface(203): surface (identity=2589) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)
06-08 10:57:59.386: E/Surface(203): surface (identity=2589) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)
06-08 10:57:59.394: E/Surface(203): surface (identity=2589) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)
06-08 10:58:00.937: I/playMedia(15072): playing Video
06-08 10:58:00.953: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:00.988: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.019: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.050: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.078: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.121: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.152: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.179: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.210: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.253: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.285: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.316: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.347: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.378: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.417: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.437: D/dalvikvm(110): GC_EXPLICIT freed 90K, 41% free 6305K/10631K, external 2194K/2740K, paused 115ms
06-08 10:58:01.449: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.480: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.511: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.554: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.585: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.621: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.652: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.687: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.714: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.746: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.781: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.812: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.847: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.882: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.914: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.949: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:01.984: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.015: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.050: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.085: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.117: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.152: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.187: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.218: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.253: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.289: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.320: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.355: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.390: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.414: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.445: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.488: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.523: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.554: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.589: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.613: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.648: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.683: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.718: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.749: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.785: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.820: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.851: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.886: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.917: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.953: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:02.988: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.023: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.058: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.097: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.117: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.152: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.183: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.222: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.246: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.281: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.316: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.347: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.382: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.417: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.449: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.484: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.515: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.550: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.585: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.617: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.656: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.691: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.714: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.749: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.781: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.816: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.851: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.882: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.917: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.953: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:03.984: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.019: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.050: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.085: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.121: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.156: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.191: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.222: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.253: E/v4l2_utils(76): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf
06-08 10:58:04.281: I/showRecord(15072): showing record menu
```

The OnPause menu

```
protected void onPause()

{

    Log.i("VideoPlayer", "onPauseCalled");
    super.onPause();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    surfaceCreated = false;
    focusFirst = false;
    if(!pm.isScreenOn())
    {
        pauseMedia();
        Log.i("onPause", " save states to be called");
        if(saveAllowed)
            saveStates();
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Log.i("onPause", "visibility GOne");
        removeListeners();
        doCleanUp();
    }

}
```

Like i said this only happens when i press home button. screen off and on and other cases work. Just get that on Home Button.

Comment: i'm having the same error in a diffrent context, and i can't find a solution yet, just note that it's not 412, it's v4l2_utils,
4L2

Comment: what context is that. But i noticed that when i get that qbuff error, its because I am doing something with a surfaceview (using pushbuffers) and not destroying it (surface view on destroy is never called thus there are problems with its buffer). At least that is what i have found.

Comment: in my case, it's because i'm trying to shrink the SurfaceView to 2x2 px.. and the low level lib can't figure out how to draw the camera preview correctly.. but you are right that it has to do with the SurfaceView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I think. 
Its because I don't pause my media or remove my Surface View when going to another activity. I think it fails on onResume(). I allowed it to pause media and set Visibility to gone outside of pm is Screen on and it stopped giving me that error